# set array inside flatlist render in react native

Tags: android, json, react-native

Hi I want to set an array for posting . Though I have already set Array for displaying in Flatlist Now I have to post . Here is my code

```
 <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View
               <Text
                style={{
                  flex: 2,
                  fontSize: 15,
                  // fontFamily: "Roboto",
                  // justifyContent: "space-between",
                  width: 150
                }}
              >

                {item.rollno}
                --
                {item.name}
              <RadioForm
                animation={true}
                buttonColor={"#C2E3A9"}
                formHorizontal={true}
                labelHorizontal={true}
                buttonStyle={{ marginRight: 20 }}
                radioStyle={{ paddingRight: 20 }}
                //  labelHorizontal={false}
                style={{
                  flex: 1,
                  paddingRight: 20,
                  flexDirection: "row",
                  //padding: 10,
                  width: 30
                }}
                radio_props={radio_props}
                initial={this.state.value}
                onPress={value => {
                  this.setState({ value: value });
                }}
                ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
```

How I want set Array because I want post .I want like this  [enter link description here][1]

[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/jensbits/MWSeg/. How I can do this .

Answer (score 0):

You need to do just 2 things to add new post value in flatlist array

1 push posted data in state and re-render

```
this.state.data.push(newPost) // push data
this.setState({ }) // update state for re-render
```

2 Update flatList

```
   extraData={this.state}
    //for example
   <FlatList
     data={this.state.data}
     extraData={this.state}     
     renderItem={({ item }) => (
     <View
     //Your stuff
    </View>
</FlatList>
```

Comment: Hi I can access full array but i want access object and bind that other array for example [
    {
        "id": 11,
        "rollno": 987,
        "name": "Farzana"
    },
    {
        "id": 12,
        "rollno": 234,
        "name": "Shamim"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "rollno": 1170001,
        "name": "RAKA"
    }] I want to access only rollno

Comment: use for loop or map  function

Comment: I used loop for(var i=0;i<numstudent;i++){
       data1={"rollno": this.state.data.rollno, "typeofattendence": this.state.typeofattendance};
       datatest.push(data1);
  } here i got rollno": this.state.data.rollno as undefined though I set this constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      rollno:"",
      typeofattendance:1,
      //radio_props: radio_props.value,
      animating: true
      //test_data:test_data,
    };
  }